# SharePoint Online getFileByServerRelativeUrl with Editor not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, editor

I am trying to get the 'Editor/Name' using REST however this does not appear to be working.

My current REST url is formed as follows:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitecollection/Documents/MyDocument.pptx')?$select=Title,InternalName,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor
```

This currently just returns the Title however I want to return the 'Editor' name.  I have tried multiple instances of this including expanding **'Editor/Id'** however to no avail.

Can anyone advise on why this is not working please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust the endpoint a bit. Need to specify `ListItemAllFields,ModifiedBy` as expand param and also specify `Title,ModifiedBy,ListItemAllFields/InternalName` as select values.

Replace the internal name with the actual name of the column in your SP Doc lib.

Modify the endpoint as below:

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitecollection/Documents/MyDocument.pptx')?
$select=Title,ModifiedBy,ListItemAllFields/InternalName&$expand=ListItemAllFields,ModifiedBy
```

Comment: Hi Guatam, sorry for the late reply. I have just had the chance to come back to this. Unfortunately this does not work for me, what I should have expanded on within my ticket is that when using ModifiedBy I get the error: "User cannot be found"

Answer (score 2):

Answer that was provided by Gautam Sheth is great!

As alternative you can use endpoint - `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle`

If you know ID of listitem\document try:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(1)?$select=Title,InternalName,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor/Id
```

Where 1 is document Id.